# Как реализовать - нажал кнопку подгрузилась информация с другой страницы?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Как реализовать?
На странице `5 блоков` с данными. У каждого блока есть `свой график`. Над блоком стоит кнопка `"График"`
При нажатии на кнопку над блоком 1 подгружается и выводится под кнопкой на этой же страницей  график взятый со страницы `grafik1.php`
 Повторное нажатие закрывает этот блок. На странице 5 блоков, а значит подгрузок таких при нажатии будет 5. Не должно быть конфликтов между собой. До нажатия кнопки `данные со страницы grafik1.php не должны загружаться.`
Спасибо

Comment: сделайте просто скрытие/появление контента при нажатии кнопки. можно через js сlassList.toggle добавлять и убирать класс, который будет делает контент невидимым.

Comment: @Макс Максимус Мне важно что-бы содержимое страницы grafik1.php не подгружалось до нажатия кнопки "График" и не было в исходном коде основной страницы.

Comment: если подключена jquery можете использовать load(), вешаете событие нажатия на на нужную кнопку: $( "#result" ).load( "grafic.php" );

Comment: @МаксМаксимус содержимое странице grafic.php появится боком на основной странице или откроется страница grafic.php?  Можете пример маленький показать?

Comment: вам вернется html код страницы, который вы сможете вставить уже куда вам нужно

Comment: @МаксМаксимус Максим Вы о таком примере говорите https://html5css.ru/edithtm/index.php ?

Comment: не знаю как там реализовано, но визуальный эффект будет такой же

Comment: @МаксМаксимус Максим в том примере почему-то не после нажатия на кнопку ничего не происходит. Вы можете на основании того примера да ответ но чтоб код сработал?

Comment: скиньте ваш код чтоб было предметнее

Comment: @МаксМаксимус Код основной страницы или код grafic1.php?

Comment: лучше оба. будет понятнее

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108183/discussion-between-arcadiy-and--).

Comment: @МаксМаксимус Содержимое основной страницы и страницы grafic1.php не могу скинуть, так как там много токенов и ключей. Не вижу препятствий вам показать мне ответ без наличия данной информации